# Preventing premature session fixture teardown when rerunning tests

Tags: python, pytest

I'm setting up some configuration in conftest.py for rerunning failed pytest tests in specific cases.

This function has been added to conftest.py. The idea is that a test can be set to retry by using the request fixture to set request.node.retry to True.

```
def pytest_runtest_protocol(item, nextitem):
"""Checks for manual mark and if found, reruns test if requested"""
if item.get_closest_marker("manual") is None:
    return

# Infinite loop for rerunning tests
while True:
    # Run test and get result
    item.ihook.pytest_runtest_logstart(
        nodeid=item.nodeid,
        location=item.location
    )

    # Hangs on this line on retry
    reports = runtestprotocol(item, nextitem=nextitem)

    # Check results
    if not getattr(item, 'retry', False):
        for report in reports:
            item.ihook.pytest_runtest_logreport(report=report)
        return True
    else:
        delattr(item, 'retry')
```

This works when multiple tests are being run, but if only one test is being run, or the test is the last in a series, then the first failure of the test causes teardown of all fixtures. Function-level fixtures are fine to be set up again (in fact, I want them to be to ensure clean state) but session-level fixtures are also torn down, and I need them to restart the test.

Is there any way to prevent the session-level fixture teardown until I'm ready?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was a bit of a hack - it's adding a dummy test that doesn't get logged.

Install pytest-ordering. Add a new file with a dummy test somewhere marked as last, e.g.

```
@pytest.mark.last
def test_dummy():
    assert True
```

Then in the pytest_runtest_protocol function, skip the dummy test right at the start:

```
def pytest_runtest_protocol(item, nextitem):
    if item.name == 'test_dummy':
        return False
    # Rest of function
```

As the last function will always be the dummy function which can't be retried, the session fixtures will be valid going into the test and will only be torn down afterwards.